# Moving Wordpress Site from one Cpanel Account to Another

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I can't find an answer to this particular question.

I have two cpanel accounts and I want to move my wordpress webiste from the original cpanel account to the new cpanel account.

I've tried downloading all the wordpress files and that didn't work. I've tried downloading all the files from the original site via WinSCP and that didn't work either.

I have been learning about and using various languages to create websites, etc. But I only know enough to be dangerous. So. The best answer would be one that's very literal to what steps I need to take using basic, regular-person English.

I hope someone can help!

Comment: Hey Kari - this is perhaps a wider ranging question than you might expect! One thing you might get some mileage out of, though, is not simply copying files, but installing a fresh WP on the second Cpanel account, and handling the transfer via a WP backup/restore plugin. There are plenty of 'em.

Comment: Yes right, as Cameron said. install a fresh wordpress site and use this plugin for example https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/ on your old site to export, and the same plugin on the new site to import the data

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress sites operate through a database so you can't simply copy files from one cPanel to another. There are a few different ways.

**Method 1: Use a plugin**

Create a fresh Wordpress on your new cPanel then use a migration plugin such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

**Method 2: Do it manually**

This is more complicated but I find it more reliable. The steps are as follows:

1. Download your Wordpress files
2. Use phpMyAdmin on your cPanel to export your wordpress database (SQL export) - https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/export-mysql-database-with-phpmyadmin
3. If you are changing domains then you need to use a text editor on your SQL export to find and replace any instance of your old domain to your new one
4. Export your theme options (f you have them). There should be a theme option that says import/export and a long string to copy
5. Now you're ready to import
6. Upload your wordpress files to your new cPanel
7. Import your database in phpMyAdmin
8. Go to the home folder of your Wordpress install and edit the wp-config.php files to include your new database details (username, password, database name)
9. Login to Wordpress and import your theme options by copying the long string from point 4 into the import box (if you have options)
10. You should be done

Before doing any kind of migration make sure you have a back-up of your Wordpress site